# After applying patches and rebooting, RHEL 5.3 hangs on udev

Tags: redhat, rhel5, udev, hangs

I suspect that one of the packages in the last system updated is causing problems with the system rebooting.  When I reboot, the server hangs on udev.

Here are a list of the updates that preceeded the problem:

```
Oct 21 18:04:03 Updated: 6:kdelibs-3.5.4-26.el5_7.1.x86_64
Oct 21 18:04:06 Updated: httpd-2.2.3-53.el5_7.3.x86_64
Oct 21 18:04:07 Updated: postgresql-libs-8.1.23-1.el5_7.2.x86_64
Oct 21 18:04:08 Updated: 1:mod_ssl-2.2.3-53.el5_7.3.x86_64
Oct 21 18:04:10 Updated: 6:kdelibs-devel-3.5.4-26.el5_7.1.x86_64
Oct 21 18:04:11 Updated: 1:autofs-5.0.1-0.rc2.156.el5_7.3.x86_64
Oct 21 18:04:12 Updated: httpd-manual-2.2.3-53.el5_7.3.x86_64
Oct 21 18:04:14 Updated: kernel-headers-2.6.18-274.7.1.el5.x86_64
Oct 21 18:04:15 Updated: 1:php-pear-1.9.4-3.el5.remi.noarch
Oct 21 18:04:30 Installed: kernel-xen-2.6.18-274.7.1.el5.x86_64
Oct 21 18:04:39 Installed: kernel-devel-2.6.18-274.7.1.el5.x86_64
Oct 21 18:04:50 Updated: 6:kdelibs-3.5.4-26.el5_7.1.i386
Oct 21 18:04:51 Updated: postgresql-libs-8.1.23-1.el5_7.2.i386
Oct 21 18:04:53 Updated: 6:kdelibs-devel-3.5.4-26.el5_7.1.i386
```

/var/log/messages shows that the system went down for reboot, but nothing was logged when the machine tried to come back (and hung at udev).  It's not saying udev failed, just prints udev and hangs.

Interestingly, when the system was hard-reset it booted without an issue (udev OK).  Issued shutdown -r, and the system hung on udev.  Again, held the power button to kill the system.  Turned it back on after the hard-reset and it came up (udev OK).  It's up now after the hard-reset.

System:
RHEL release 5.7 (Tikanga) Kernel 2.6.18-274.7.1.el5xen (x86_64) (Dell Poweredge)

Any ideas on which of these packages could cause udev to hang?

Comment: Does your clock drift too? You could try adding this to your boot line in grub: clocksource=acpi_pm

Comment: This seems random on first read.. How does this address the udev  issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was resolved after ultimately removing OpenManage tool.  Prior to this, Dell diagnosed hardware issues and had replaced essentially the entire system (except case drives and ram).  Removing OpenManage fixed the problem of the system panicking when starting udev.

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced problems with exactly kernel version 2.6.18-274.7.1.el5 making multithreaded applications hang when reading `/proc/stat`

There are also others that have had similar problems with exactly this kernel:
http://projects.puppetlabs.com/issues/10819.

Try boot a slightly older kernel and see if it goes away...

Jarl